# MS Reports rdlc c# win forms multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc, page-break

I am trying to create a Report with two columns.

Records should add in as below...

```
1.Bob   6.Sarch
2.Sue   7.Barrie
3.Adam  8.James
4.Dave  9.Steve
5.Robin 10.Euan

11.Fred
12.Heidi
13.Liz
```

For the first column (1-5 in this example), a page break should wrap the data to the second column (6-10). After the second column is full (11-13) the the data should page wrap.

The data used to generate the report will have a fixed number of columns. The height and width required for the data will not change.

I am using with C#, WinForms, .net4. I have tried several various approaches with no success. Thus far I have only managed

```
1.Bob   2.Sue
3.Adam...
```

Please help or point me in the right direction :-)

Many Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. I'm not sure if this can be done in reports though (that is, I don't believe there's any built-in control that can render like that).

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR ---> This isn't possible with SSRS, afaik.

---

If I understand correctly, you want to list the items in a data set, that when rendered with a [hard page break renderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210530.aspx#RenderingExtensions) will render with these requirements:

- items are added vertically as long as there's space on the page
- a new column of items is started when the first column ran out of space, vertically
- a page break is inserted when the second column filled up the vertical space, thus starting a new, first column on a new page

Now, there's [only these controls in SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159267%28v=sql.100%29):

- Textbox
- Table, Matrix
- Chart
- Gauge
- List
- Image
- Subreport
- Line, Rectangle

Out of these only the Tablix (Table/Matrix) and List are remotely capable of such a thing, but they can't satisfy your requirements. I'm afraid the **answer to your question** is that this **can't be (easily) done**.

The hard way that this may still be possible is perhaps by creating a [custom report item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345231.aspx) and/or by creating a [custom rendering extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153624.aspx). But that may be overkill for just wanting to create a nice little list.